# What is the default CSS of a textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea, default

I am trying to make an ordered list go by the side of a textarea, such that it has line numbers, but I can't seem to make the textarea and the ordered list line up. I don't know the default CSS for a textarea that I could use on the ordered list, where could I find the default CSS of a textarea?

Comment: When I try to log the style into the console to see the default attributes, it shows them all the possible attributes listed in an object with each's value being an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check default values from browser developer console.
When you click an HTML tag, It will show all applied CSS to your selected element.

Also you can use this link. It has all elements and default styles.

[Click](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)

For example, `textarea` has no default styling on it.

You mentioned log outing your element to console and all values seems empty string. It is because `textarea` has no default styling on it.

Comment: How does a textarea have no default styling when it has a different font? Is there a way I could make the ordered list fit the same styling as the textarea?

Comment: I think `textarea` does not applies fonts. If you want to inherit your font in textarea, you can use `font-family: inherit` on textarea styling.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, if you want the textarea to match up with something, like the lines, you would have to manually set the styling of the textarea and the styling of the thing you want to match with it. If you like the textarea for the font where every character is the same width, the consolas font is a good font to use.

CSS:

```
#objtextdiv{
  background-color:#eecccc44;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  padding:0 0 0 30px;
  left:0%;
  height:100%;
}
#objtext{
  font-family:"Lucida Console",Monoco,monospace;
  font-size:14px;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:99%;
  background-color:#eeeeee44;
  resize:horizontal;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
}
#linenumbersdiv{
  font-family:"Lucida Console",Monoco,monospace;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:40px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:lime;
  margin-left:-10px;
  padding:0px;
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  padding-left:0;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
#linenumberslist{
  font-size:14px;
  display:block;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:0;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="linenumbersdiv">
      <ol id="linenumberslist">
        <li id="theone">what</li>
        <!--li>ahh</li>
        <li>AHHHH</li-->
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div id="objtextdiv">
    <textarea id="objtext">
etc etc etc
    </textarea>
    </div>
```